# Trouble formatting x-axis in ggplot2. I want discrete points but get continous

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the data set

```
Deciles  Probabilities
1        0.5002026
2        0.5228149
3        0.5388775
4        0.5408937
5        0.5419471
6        0.5467041
7        0.5528741
8        0.5699044
9        0.5934170
10       0.7033443
```

with structure

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Deciles      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ Probabilities: num  0.5 0.523 0.539 0.541 0.542 ...
```

Then I want to plot `Deciles` on the x-axis vs `Probabilties` on the y-axis such that the x-axis starts from 10 and goes down to 1, one step at a time. I did the following:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Deciles, y = Probabilities)) + 
  geom_line(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2)+
  xlim(1, 10) + 
  scale_x_reverse()
```

Then I get the plot below. But looking at the x-axis I see two problems:

1. All the deciles get a decimal number tagged on. The deciles are integers and I don't want that.
2. I want ALL the ten deciles to show. Right now 1,3,4,6,8 and 9 are missing.

How can I fix the above problems?

[image]

Comment: you need to use `scale_x_reverse(breaks = 10:1)`

Comment: Ok that solved the problem. Thank you! However, let's say I don't want to reverse the x-scale. If I just remove the `scale_x_reverse()` I get the same problem but now x-axis start from a 1 that's not even visible.

Comment: then `scale_x_continouos(breaks = 1:10)` will do. Also: you will have a warning. That's coz you shouldn't use `xlim` and `scale_x_...` together. `scale_x_...` already has an argument called `limits=` that you can use instead of `xlim`

Comment: Try changing the class of Deciles to factor with as.factor(Deciles). If you don't want to change the class of your original data you can add it in the aes of ggplot.

Comment: @CeciliaLópez: you need to add `group=1` in `aes` to have it work.

Comment: @Cecilia López: I did that and I dont get any warning at all or an error, the figure with corect axis appear but there is no line at all ontop.

Comment: @CeciliaLópez: Ok that last of your comment fixed it. Thank you, now I know two ways.